# Haskell monad flow understanding

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, monads

I will restate my questions with examples at the bottom.

When I say `m` or `k` I am referring to the left and right values in the function call, `m >>= k`.

There's this blur in understanding of monads. If `m` is a computation and `k` is a lambda expression, does that mean that `k` serves two purposes where it can work with bindings in the do block using it and also be used for some other purpose in the Monad instance definition? If a value is bound right before `k` is evaluated in its do block, will values be automatically passed to it or is the Monad instance methods definition where we define the sole effect of propagation to `k`?

I may be a bit mislead by the examples I see that always pass the directly previous bound item to the lambda expression when explaining monads. Even when the notation used is pure-do-no-lambda, is it always the last bound item that is passed to the hidden lambda, under the hood. Now, is it bad practice to use a lambda that takes more than one argument and use it as `k` in `m >>= k`? Or am I wrong in assuming that if we are working in a do block, under the hood, only one argument is passed to the next 'hidden' lambda expression and that this one argument is the immediate previously bound item?

I will now restate my questions with examples.

```
do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    putStrLn $ a ++ b
```

`a` and `b` are bound to values in `IO` container that is returned from running `getLine`. Under the hood, which of the following is equivalent, if any?

```
getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

*OR*

```
getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \(a, b) -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

We see that the value in the `IO` container of `getLine` is extracted and passed onto the lambda expression.

If the first is correct, wouldn't that cause an error since `a` would be undefined in the monad definition?

I pulled the second out of thin air. I've seen no evidence that it could be this, but even if it isn't the correct answer, can we do something like that? Of course, we would have to make all lambda expressions used with `>>=` all take 2-tuples in this context. Is this behaviour not solely dictated by our `>>=` definition, at least when only-lambda-no-do notation is used?

Can we use this lambda expression in the monad definition and pass something to it causing it to print screen again? Should we?

If we wanted to work with `putStrLn` in the `>>=` definition, would we have to pass some arbitrary value to `k` in order to get the `putStrLn` function out?

Thank you. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

I will only give you a partial answer, as I didn't understand, what exactly you are asking. Sorry for that.

```
do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    putStrLn $ a ++ b
```

is equivalent to

```
getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

and this works, because

```
\b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

creates a function, which captures `a` from the scope it is defined
in. If the is no such `a` in the scope of this term, the compiler will complain about `a` not being in scope.

Let's expand that a little and take a look at

```
\a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

again. This defines a function, which if applied to some value `x` returns the result of the expression

```
getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (x ++ b)
```

Here the variable `a` got replaced by the value `x`. So there is no more `a` to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

`do` notation like this:

```
do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    putStrLn $ a ++ b
```

is equivalent to

```
getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

This, again, is equivalent to

```
getLine >>= (\a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b))
```

Notice the extra brackets. The first `getLine` is composed with a lambda expression where `a` is the 'contained element'. Inside of this lambda expression, a new expression is invoked. That expression is

```
getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

This expression is still 'inside' the first lambda expression, which means that `a` is still in scope.

You can put even more brackets around expressions, if it helps:

```
getLine >>= (\a -> getLine >>= (\b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)))
```

These brackets are entirely redundant, but they highlight how the various expressions are scoped. Notice that both `a` and `b` are still in scope when `putStrLn (a ++ b)` is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Unsugared `do block` will be like `getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)` you don't need to pass all parameters from previous call because of local scopes, let's denote them:

```
getLine >>= 
(!This is first closure! \a -> getLine >>= 
(!This is second, all variables from the first 
closure are available, because in haskell function closure takes outer scope in! \b -> 
putStrLn(a ++ b) !End of the second closure!) !End of the first closure!)
```

And now about type of (>>=). GHCI prints next `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.
So `k` is just a lambda that `Monad m` will work with, all it have to do is "implement interface" for `>>=`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the `do` equivalent to the following?
>
> ```
> getLine >>= \a -> getLine >>= \b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)
> ```

Yes, this one.

> If the first is correct, wouldn't that cause an error since a would be undefined in the monad definition?

No. The `->` arrow syntax is right-associative:

```
getLine >>= (\a -> getLine >>= (\b -> putStrLn (a ++ b)))
```

It forms a closure where `a` is still in scope.

Comment: Note that the `>>=` operator is actually left associative.  It's just that the lambda syntax `\x -> ...` is a special syntactic form that gobbles up "as much as it can".